# Count and display frequently occuring strings (Java)

Tags: java

How do I keep track of the DNA strand with the smallest and largest number of each of the nucleobases and print those strands to the output?

Lets say I write this into the console(when I type "end" the output will display):

```
A   
CC   
AATA   
GGG  
TTT  
end
```

The console should produce output that's like this:

```
A count: 4  
C count: 2  
G count: 3  
T count: 4  
Low A count: CC  
High A count: AATA  
Low C count: A  
High C count: CC  
Low G count: A  
High G count: GGG  
Low T count: A  
High T count: TTT
```

Here is my code:

```
package com.trouen;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class DNA {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        process(s);
    }

    public static void process(Scanner s) {

        int aCount = 0;
        int cCount = 0;
        int gCount = 0;
        int tCount = 0;

        String lowACount = null;
        String lowCCount = null;
        String lowGCount = null;
        String lowTCount = null;

        String highACount = null;
        String highCCount = null;
        String highGCount = null;
        String highTCount = null;

        String printout = null;

        while (s.hasNext()) {

            String input = s.next();

            for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
                if (input.charAt(i) == 'A') {
                    aCount++;
                } else if (input.charAt(i) == 'C') {
                    cCount++;
                    // lowCCount = input;
                } else if (input.charAt(i) == 'G') {
                    gCount++;
                    // lowGCount = input;
                } else if (input.charAt(i) == 'T') {
                    tCount++;
                    // lowTCount = input;
                }

            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("end")) {
                break;
            }
        }

        s.close();

        System.out.println("A count: " + aCount);
        System.out.println("C count: " + cCount);
        System.out.println("G count: " + gCount);
        System.out.println("T count: " + tCount);
        System.out.println("Low A count: " + lowACount);
        System.out.println("High A count: " + highACount);
        System.out.println("Low C count: " + lowCCount);
        System.out.println("High C count: ");
        System.out.println("Low G count: " + lowGCount);
        System.out.println("High G count: ");
        System.out.println("Low T count: " + lowTCount);
        System.out.println("High T count: ");

    }
}
```

I seem to have gotten the counting the amount of letters down, but I can't seem to figure out how to make the program sort out the low's and high's of each letter. I'm not allowed to use any type of collection, OOP, or arrays. Everything should be done in the process method. Can anyone help me?

Comment: This is incredibly similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269802/how-to-get-the-low-and-high-counts-of-characters-from-a-string

Comment: Yes but that question doesn't have any information that helps. The answers aren't exactly what the question is looking for.

Comment: In fact I did not mark this as a duplicate. However, @DavidWallace's answer can be a good starting point.

Comment: I don't understand it though. I really just need help from someone.

Comment: This is EXTREMELY similar to what Stefano suggested you look at. Someone already did this homework assignment for you.

Comment: What the other person did I have already done. I'm concerned about the next step at the moment that calculates the high's and low's of each letter.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Can you give me some pseudocode or something to work off of? I have been stuck on this for the past 4 hours and I feel so helpless.

Comment: @Globmont I'm working on Adept at the moment.

Comment: @user122947 Assuming you are in the same class I am in, you are indeed allowed to use arrays. He said not to use ArrayLists because that gets into the OOP area. Look at my answer for a basic method

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to go about keeping track is to use 2 arrays. The first array would be 2 dimensional. It should have 4 rows and 2 columns, or the other way around. I'll be working with 4 columns 2 rows for this example. Each column represents one of A, C, T or G. Then the two rows for that column represent the Strings that have the highest and lowest occurrences of that nucleotide. Similarly, make another 2x4 array and store the count values in that array. This way, you can compare the values from the second array, and store them in the first.

Edit: Pseudoish/Java Sample code

```
String[][] sequences = [4][2];
int[][] sequenceCounts = [4][2];

//put your looping code to read in and process each of the sequences here

int numA = findPattern(currentSequence, "A");
int numC = findPattern(currentSequence, "C");
int numG = findPattern(currentSequence, "G");
int numT = findPattern(currentSequence, "T");

if(/* check for whether the current sequence has less A/C/G/Ts than the previous minimum */)
{

}

if(/*check for whether the current sequence has more A/C/G/T than the previous maximum*/)
{

}
```

This should get you started (hopefully). The `findPattern` method is one that you will have to write i.e. it is not included in Java. I'm actually heading to dinner now so I'll be afk for like an hour or two but I'll come back! Fear not!

Comment: Could you provide some boiler plate as a small example that I can buiild of? It's hard to visualize that. Thank you so much for helping me out btw.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.trouen;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class DNA {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    process(s);
}

public static void process(Scanner s) {
while (s.hasNext()) {
    String input = s.next();
if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("end")    
{
      break;
}
else
{
    ACount = ACount + findPattern(input,'A');
    CCount = CCount + findPattern(input,'C');
    GCount = GCount + findPattern(input,'G');
    TCount = TCount + findPattern(input,'T');

    if(c == 0)
    {
        lowA = ACount;
        highA = ACount;
        lowAVal = input;
        highAVal = input;

        lowC = CCount;
        highC = CCount;
        lowCVal = input;
        highCVal = input;

        lowG = GCount;
        highG = GCount;
        lowGVal = input;
        highGVal = input;

        lowT = TCount;
        highT = TCount;
        lowTVal = input;
        highTVal = input;
    }
    else
    {
        if(ACount < lowA)
        {
            lowAVal = input;
        }
        if(ACount > highA)
        {
            highAVal = input;
        }
        lowA = ACount;
        highA = ACount;

        if(CCount < lowC)
        {
            lowCVal = input;
        }
        if(CCount > highC)
        {
            highCVal = input;
        }
        lowC = CCount;
        highC = CCount;

        if(GCount < lowG)
        {
            lowGVal = input;
        }
        if(GCount > highG)
        {
            highGVal = input;
        }
        lowG = GCount;
        highG = GCount;

        if(TCount < lowT)
        {
            lowTVal = input;
        }
        if(TCount > highT)
        {
            highTVal = input;
        }
        lowT = TCount;
        highT = TCount;
    }
}
}
s.close();

    System.out.println("A count: " + ACount);
    System.out.println("C count: " + CCount);
    System.out.println("G count: " + GCount);
    System.out.println("T count: " + TCount);
    System.out.println("Low A count: " + lowAVal);
    System.out.println("High A count: " + highAVal);
    System.out.println("Low C count: " + lowCVal);
    System.out.println("High C count: "+highCVal);
    System.out.println("Low G count: " + lowGVal);
    System.out.println("High G count: "+highGVal);
    System.out.println("Low T count: " + lowTVal);
    System.out.println("High T count: "+highTVal);

}

public int findPattern(String strValue,char checkChar)throws Exception
   {
       int count = 0;
       for(int i=0;i<strValue.length();i++)
       {
           if(strValue.charAt(i) == checkChar)
           {
               count++;
           }
       }
       return count;
   }
}
you can use this to get low and high count.
```